# Angular select populate dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, json, ng-options

This is my JSON data:

```
[{
  "table":"mCity",
  "drpdownItems":[
     {
        "Display":"ab",
        "Value":1
     },
     {
        "Display":"a",
        "Value":10
     },
     {
        "Display":"Delhi",
        "Value":7
     },
     {
        "Display":"Devgad",
        "Value":4
     },
     {
        "Display":"Kalyan",
        "Value":5
     },
     {
        "Display":"Mumbai",
        "Value":2
     },
     {
        "Display":"Nashik",
        "Value":9
     },
     {
        "Display":"New Mumbais",
        "Value":6
     },
     {
        "Display":"Panji ",
        "Value":8
     },
     {
        "Display":"Pune",
        "Value":3
     }
  ]
}]
```

I want the following output:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">ab</option>
    <option value="10">a</option>
    <option value="7">Delhi</option>
</select>
```

I tried following:

```
ng-options="City.Display as City.Value for drpdownItems in CmbsData.table['mCity']"
```

Comment: Try this `ng-options="City.Display as City.Value for drpdownItems in CmbsData.drpdownItems"`

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-options="City.Display as City.Value for drpdownItems in CmbsData[0].drpdownItems"
```

Cmbs is an array, and drpdownItems is a property of the object which is the first element of that array

Edit based on comment: generalized form
    ng-options="City.Display as City.Value for drpdownItems in (CmbsData | filter:{table:'mCity'}).drpdownItems"

Comment: I want to filter where table is 'mCity'. Don't want to hard code with index.
There is chance i will get multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on comment below:**

```
<select 
    ng-options="City.Value as City.Display for City in (CmbsData | filter:{table:'mCity'}:true|limitTo:1)[0].drpdownItems"
    ng-model="selectedCity">
</select>
```

In order to make a strict match, please use `true` in your `filter. It is better to use`limitTo:1`because there may be multiple matches.`filter`and`limitTo`always result in an array. Since we are limiting by 1, we can use`[0]` index to get the city we want.

**Original answer:**

You need to use like this

```
<select name="" id="" ng-options="City.Value as City.Display for City in CmbsData[0].drpdownItems" ng-model="selectedCity"></select>
```

The syntax of `ng-options` is `_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_`

Comment: I want to filter where table is 'mCity'. Don't want to hard code with index